# TortoiseSVN Error HTTP 503 'Service Unavailable' when committing .bat file

Tags: svn

I'm just trying to commit a .bat file to my repository and I get an error that reads "Unexpected HTTP status 503 'Service Unavailable' on 'svn/[repository]/Test.bat".

In the config file for SVN on the client I tried uncommenting enable-auto-props = yes and then added this to the [auto-props] section;
*.bat = svn:eol-style=native
There is no change, I still get the same error when trying to commit the .bat file. If I change the time name to Test.bat.txt then I can commit it OK.

What do I need to do to commit this .bat file?

Answer (score 3):

Check the server's log and config (e.g. `httpd.conf`). It seems that the server was configured to reject commits that contain certain filenames. That's normally done with *-commit hook scripts and you could add an informative message instead of `503 Service Unavailable. But in this particular case it seems that the check is performed by the Apache and it just sends HTTP status 503 when commit contains *.bat files.

An antivirus on client or server side could also cause this behavior. Anyway, check the log on the server and its config -- they will point you to the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think the issue is on the client's antivirus as this client recently started blocking any https sites that are not trusted. I then applied the SSL I already had to my SVN Server and that worked fine but now it appears that .bats can't be uploaded. Before the client made this change the .bat file was not an issue. I tested uploading/committing a .bat file from another clients site and that worked fine.